# Crash when moving item from one UICollectionView Section to another, then deleting that item

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that has two sections, each filling up cells with separate arrays.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 && GlobalList.priorityArray.count != 0 {

        return GlobalList.priorityArray.count

    } else if section == 1 && GlobalList.listItemArray.count != 0 {

        return GlobalList.listItemArray.count

    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sections
}
```

I can move items between sections without any issues. I also can delete items. My problem occurs when I move an item between sections, reload data, then try to delete all the items in that section, I get the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Here are the methods I have created to deal with deleting and moving items

Moving Items:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                             to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (sourceIndexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {

        listItem = GlobalList.priorityArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)

    } else if (sourceIndexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1 {

        listItem = GlobalList.listItemArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)

    }

    if (destinationIndexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {

        GlobalList.priorityArray.insert(listItem, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

    } else if (destinationIndexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1 {

        GlobalList.listItemArray.insert(listItem, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

    }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
```

Deleting Items:

```
    func deleteItem(sender: UIButton) {

    let point : CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, to: collectionView)
    let i = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: point)
    print("deleting.. \(String(describing: i))")
    let index = i
    GlobalList.listItemArray.remove(at: (index?.row)!)
    deleteItemCell(indexPath: i!)

}

func deleteItemCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Let me know if anything else is needed to figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling `self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])` directly instead of inside a perform batch updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had a similar issue with the `collectionView` when calling `reloadData` and then directly after trying to insert cells into the `collectionView`. I solved this issue by instead manually deleting and inserting sections in the `collectionView` inside a perform batch updates, like so:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] () in
    self?.collectionView.deleteSections([0])
    self?.collectionView.insertSections([0])
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can this be used to deleted items, I see you mention sections?

Comment: Yeah just update the dataSource before calling this and it should delete them.